# Заменить ключи в таблице на значения из другой таблицы

Tags: php, mysql

У меня имеется такая структура бд

```
+---Города----+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Москва |
|  2 | Киев   |
|  3 | Лондон | 
+----+--------+

+----+--------Маршруты-----------------+
| id | from      | to                  |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 | 1         | 2                   |
|  2 | 3         | 1                   |
|  3 | 2         | 3                   |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
```

Мне нужно сделать выборку из таблицы "Маршруты" так, что бы получить:

```
+----+--------Маршруты-----------------+
| id | from      | to                  |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 | Москва    | Киев                |
|  2 | Лондон    | Москва              |
|  3 | Киев      | Лондон              |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
```

Есть идеи?

Comment: @Aventus1, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это называется джойнами - объединением таблиц для выборки. Джойн объединяет таблицу (как правило, это делается для удобства по алиасам таблиц), и в SELECT поля указываются как `table_alias.field` (никто не запрещает указать и просто field, если в результирующей выборке будет только одно поле с таким названием).

```
SELECT r.id, cf.name AS departure, ct.name AS destination
FROM routes AS r
LEFT JOIN cities AS cf ON cf.id = r.`from` -- добавляем в запрос таблицу cities, по правилу "в каждую строку добавляются данные, чей id соответствует полю from"
LEFT JOIN cities AS ct ON ct.id = r.to -- то же самое, но по полю to
```